# White Screen on Note 2, cannot flash and cannot access recovery mode

Tags: recovery-mode, odin

Tried to do factory reset from phone settings but now only a white screen appears. I cannot access recovery mode but I can access download mode. Tried to flash it with odin but it seems the PIT table was not found. Tried to do a repartition with a PIT file but Odin returns a fail. How can i recover the PIT table?